# Empty a file and store a state permanently

Tags: elixir

I would like to use a file to store some variables. The file will be rewritten every 10/15 minutes, and the data should stay there after the app shut down. Is there a solution which is not closing and opening the file every time? I cannot see how to empty a file through IO or File.

Comment: Have you considered using [dets](http://erlang.org/doc/man/dets.html)?

Comment: never heard of it actually

Comment: Just a note: depending on where you're app runs the file system might not be a safe place to store state. Heroku for example provides no guarantees whatsoever about keeping written files around (in cases like this the file system is called "ephemeral").

Comment: so in that case how do I achieve the above without a file? is dets the answer? any elixir tool?

Comment: AFAIK `dets` just uses the file system under the hood. If your app runs in an ephemeral file system you'll probably have to reach for a more traditional solution such as Redis or any other persistent storage solution.

Comment: Heroku for example offers a free-tier option on Postgres and Redis. As long as you only need to keep small amounts of data there (which I assume you want to based on your question) that should be perfectly sufficient.

Comment: I'm more concerned with the cost of the operation. Accessing a file is less expensive than making a query to a db, and the data are really few fields, 2 or 3.

Comment: I totally understand but as long as your app runs in an ephemeral file system your options are limited. You might want to consider using a caching library like [`nebulex`](https://hexdocs.pm/nebulex/getting-started.html) which keeps the values in memory but also writes them to a persistent storage like Redis (in case the node goes down). Seems to check all your boxes.

Comment: If you want to read/write a file, you have to open/close it. It's how it works, and there is no way around it. If you want to avoid this you need to do caching, and async writebacks to disk or something similar.

Comment: It seems like you're concerned with the performance of something that only happens every 10/15 minutes - I would say that's premature optimization. If it's really a problem, make a worker that keeps the state in memory, returns from memory on read, persists to file on write, and initializes from this file on app start.

Comment: @PawełObrok in fact it can be that or every 10 seconds, it can vary. Moreover I need ms precision.

Comment: @PawełObrok even if, I don't think it's premature optimization. Elixir creates a new process PID every time you open a file, and I prefer that to stay the same process

Comment: @SaschaWolf I think that if you keep files under priv/ they will be conserved inside releases, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Erlang's `:file` :

```
defp empty_file(file) do
  :file.position(file,:bof)
  :file.truncate(file)
  file
end

file
|> empty_file()
|> IO.write("data")
```